# Enter Numbers Into HTML Form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 10 small text field boxes in HTML where I want users to enter numbers 1 to 10 - and the same number can not be entered twice in another box.
I'm struggling to work out how to accomplish this in Javascript/jQuery.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Any code, a fiddle perhaps? When do you want to perform this operation?

Comment: Doesn't sound particularly hard. What have you tried?

Comment: @Helen, nearly 3 years on the site, you have asked some good questions (including a popular one voted `+19`), and now you're asking this. What happened? Is someone else tinkering with your account?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I guess she didn't drink her first coffee yet.

Answer (score 1):

Simply create an array with the values and check for duplication.

```
var formdata=new Array(); 
formdata[0]=document.getElementByid('id').value;
formdata[1]=document.getElementByid('id').value;
formdata[2]=document.getElementByid('id').value;
```

Now check for duplications in the array using the following - I guess the following question would be useful on stack overflow:
[Easiest way to find duplicate values in a JavaScript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840781/easiest-way-to-find-duplicate-values-in-a-javascript-array).
If the breakpoint is one simply display an alert() to the user to renter the data.

Instead of using documents.getElementById() you can also use

```
oForm = document.forms[index];
oText = oForm.elements["text_element_name"].value; OR 
oText = oForm.elements[index].value;
```

More information can be found at:
http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-get-form.phtml